# AJAX keeping data on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have a like button that now works with Ajax. With one minor flaw. I click like on a post and it updates 1 like and shows in the page. But if I refresh the page it vanishes out of sight. The like is still in the database it just doesn't show in the page. Now someone told me to use

```
$(document).ready(function () {}
```

to do this on page load, but I have no clue how to use it to make my likes show on page refresh.
Or maybe I have to make a new call on page refresh to get all the likes for each post.

This is what I have so far

```
function likestatus(postid,contextid){
var obj = document.getElementById(contextid);
$.post("../include/like_do.php", { streamitem_id: postid},function(data){
//see the parameter data in this function. Data contains whatever that you echo in your php file.
$("#likesprint"+postid).html(data+"Likes");
 });
}
```

Like_do.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require"load.php";
if(isset($_POST['streamitem_id'])){

$check = user_core::check_liked($_SESSION['id'],$_POST['streamitem_id'],1);

user_core::do_like($_SESSION['id'],$_POST['streamitem_id'],1);

echo $check; // as your user_core::check_liked() function returns number of likes.
}else{
echo "<script>alert('Error liking post');</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Not enough info.  How do you load the like data initially?  If you are sure the like gets saved, that's where you should look -- when you reload, the initial data that comes back does not have the like data

Comment: What language are you using to generate the page? Is this not something that you can set as the page is being generated?

Comment: This is all I have. The loading part is what I need. The user clicks like goes into the above function, to the php page updates the database and collects the amount of likes. I'll add my php page.

Comment: Maybe that is the issue. I'm calling from check liked which doesn't echo out the num it just returns the value to see if the user has liked it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have managed to get it working with a simple call in my home.php file. I was just not thinking properly.